# ReportViewer, Report Filters, and Textbox Sorting: Report Disappears

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

Setting:

- rdl

  - 1 textbox with sorting (for a column header)
  - 2 report parameters set to visible
- ReportViewer

  - the 2 parameters visible as filters at top
  - sorting textbox clickable and sorts fine

Issue:

When user selects a different value from the parameters/filters (dropdowns) at the top of the report viewer, then clicks on the icon to sort (up and down arrows), the report disappears. It's just gone. The sorting doesn't fire ReportRefresh, but some other undetermined event. Unfortunately this processing knows of the change in filter and decides to suicide.

Comment: Is the user on IE or Firefox/Chrome? (sometimes FF/Cr have problems)

Comment: All browsers are effected.

Comment: Is your site behind any kind of proxy/sharepoint/gateway/relay or anything else that does URL rewriting/altering?

Comment: No: it's a problem using the built-in IIS (Visual Studio) and in all our dev/qa environments. We do not use URL rewriting.

Comment: I have seen this behavior when I forget the "If Not Page.IsPosback" within the Page_Load() sub.  I'm sure you thought of that, but I just want to confirm.